# Parser from TokenBuffer returns null on nextToken

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, java-17

I'm having issues deserializing with the following code:

```
TokenBuffer tokenBuffer = new TokenBuffer(jp);
JsonParser jp2 = tokenBuffer.asParser();

jp2.nextToken();

JsonToken nextToken = jp2.nextToken();

if (nextToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    return;
}

if (nextToken == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    return;
}

if (jp2.currentName().equals("type")) {
    jp2.nextToken();
    attributeValueType = jp2.getValueAsString();
    break;
}
```

This line gives a Null pointer:

```
if (jp2.currentName().equals("type")) {
```

And this returns null:

```
jp2.nextToken();
```

And this doesn't:

```
jp.nextToken();
```

When I do the same functions on `jp`(so not creating `jp2`),everything is fine.
When I switch back to Java 8, everything is fine.

Could Java 17 break the Jackson lib?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you get a null pointer, then `jp2.currentName()` must be giving you `null`. If getting a null value there is acceptable, then you can inverse the equality check: `"type".equals(jp2.currentName())`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that `jp2.nextToken()` also gives back null, but `jp.nextToken()` doesn't and `jp.currentName()` also gives back a value

Comment: Why do you call `jp2.nextToken()` twice? Maybe there is only one token, so the second time it quite rightly returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this works but adding this line helped:

```
tokenBuffer.copyCurrentStructure(jp);
```

So the full code now looks like this:

```
TokenBuffer tokenBuffer = new TokenBuffer(jp);
tokenBuffer.copyCurrentStructure(jp);
JsonParser jp2 = tokenBuffer.asParser();

jp2.nextToken();

JsonToken nextToken = jp2.nextToken();

if (nextToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    return;
}

if (nextToken == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    return;
}

if (jp2.currentName().equals("type")) {
    jp2.nextToken();
    attributeValueType = jp2.getValueAsString();
    break;
}
```

Like I mentioned, this is not needed when running with Java 8. It works now, so I'll close this question.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `TokenBuffer` does not have access to a node from where to start parsing. Calling `jp.nextToken()` helps with that.

```java
String carJson = "{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }";
JsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
JsonParser  jp  = factory.createParser(carJson);
jp.nextToken();

TokenBuffer tb = new TokenBuffer(jp);
tb.copyCurrentStructure(jp);
JsonParser jp2 = tb.asParser();

JsonToken tok;
do {
    tok = jp2.nextToken();
    System.out.println(tok);
} while (tok != null);
```

You can find more information on how to use a `TokenBuffer` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624347/9698467 and what the purpose of `TokenBuffer` is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848619/9698467